# How do I hide or close the MDI parent?

Tags: c#

In my project I have a MDI parent form, from that form I jump in my main program but when I enter my main program I want to close, hide or minimize the MDI , so it isn't visible for the user. I tried it by myself but it didn't work. I was wondering if it is possible and how it is possible.

```
private void bot45_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    Form2 fors = new Form2(); //main program
    fors.Show();
    //bot 45 is the button to enter the main form
    // enter main program--->> code to hide close or minimize the MDI form
}
```

Comment: looks like you might want to do ShowDialog() instead of show i think as control will not wait after show

Comment: And when do you want to show the MDI Parent again?

Comment: To minimize your current form, you can use `this.WindowState= FormWindowState.Minimized;`  or to hide it you can call `this.Hide();`

Comment: You may want to change your code to not start with the MDI Form.  The MDI Form provides some "Main Entry Point" plumbing features to the app.  If the MDI Form  is not really your main form then you may want to start with a traditional form instead of an MDI form.  Also the behavior of how these forms show up on the taskbar when minimized is a property of each form in your MDI case and that may be relevant to your goals.